# Sequence of integers

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence of integers $\left\{a_{n}\right\}$ is defined by
$$
a_{0}= 1\,,\quad a_{1}=2\,,\qquad
a_{n + 2}= a_{n} + a_{n+1}^{2}\quad\mbox{for}\quad n \geq 0
$$
What is the rest in the euclidean division of $a_{2009}$ by $7$ ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mod $7$:
$$\color{red}1,\color{red}2,5,6,6,0,6,1,0,1,\color{red}1,\color{red}2,...$$
Does this help?

Comment: *Semi* brute force. Still, +1

Comment: I'm sorry, i dont really understand

Comment: @user140161 are you familiar with number theory and modular arithmetic?

Comment: I am not. However this question is from a competition for students in grade 11 and 12

Comment: @user140161 Instead of working with the full numbers you can work with the remainders, it's like this: $2^2+1=5$, $5^2+2=27\equiv6$ remainder after division by $7$, so next is $6^2+5=41$ again $6$ remainder and so on.

Comment: @user140161 You can read up on modular arithmetic and other related concepts [in a pdf here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fmf.uni-lj.si%2F~lavric%2FSantos%2520-%2520Number%2520Theory%2520for%2520Mathematical%2520Contests.pdf&ei=FKU9U-6FAoyNrgeFloH4Cw&usg=AFQjCNGoL4iUUQOyTwbW37GyRWSGlHcMzw&sig2=5xBUoptZfU2QuNCTzsPa0g&bvm=bv.64125504,d.bmk)